# Any messaging framework for server-client communication in android?

Tags: android, database, remote-server

I have go through several posts in the internet but did not get a straight and clear answer for this.

I am doing one app on android which needs data to be sent/received from a database over internet. So how I can send/receive messages from my remote database on my android device?

Is there any messaging framework available currently in the android to do this type of task?

One method I thought of is to have PHP scripts at my web server and I will call those php scripts from my android httpClient. But its a bit tire some and error checking also a bit problem and retry mechanism also not there.

Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 2):

Google have a service for that.

[Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. As I read, with the service, I can send data from app server to android device. But how can I send data from device to app server? I have a database which need to be updated from android devices.

Comment: From the device to the server you can use a normal HTTP get or post request. So use Cloud messaging going from the server to android. Use normal HTTP request going from android to the server.

Comment: Is it like all the great applications running on web-services use HTTP-post for updating data to their servers?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging may be suitable just for sending push notifications to android devices and things like that. And XMPP could be used to send messages from one android to another. So what you have taken, using a PHP script and calling it using a URLConnection or HTTPConnection is a better way to make transaction with a remote database